# How to redirect at Home page if any router does not exist in Jhipster Angular 4 App?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, jhipster, jhipster-registry

**I want to redirect at Home page if user type any URL which is not exist in system**

Answer (score 2):

In [`app.module.ts`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/fd572c5f8b2609b581955752603e83ace4de0aa3/src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts#L33), add the following line to the `imports` list, after the other modules.  If it's added before other routes, it will redirect to home for those routes.

```
RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '**',   redirectTo: '/' }])
```

You'll also need to import `RouterModule`:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon for your answer 

I have added object that you have given me like beloved code but It always (in all right & wrong)  Redirects to home,

` const LAYOUT_ROUTES = [
    navbarRoute,
    ...errorRoute,
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
]; `

** it redirect to home for all routers (exist & non-exists both)**

Comment: You're right.  The wildcard route has to go after the other routes or it won't work.  I updated the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Ruddell, now it is working fine for me.

but it is not working when I enter wrong SubRoutes. for Ex:- localhost:8080/customer/XYZ. here customer is one route but XYZ is not any sub route.

Thanks you so much for correct answer and please give me solution for any another problem too.

Comment: Is the wildcard route located after your entity module import in app.module.ts?  I can't reproduce what you mentioned (note you are missing the `#` in the url)

Comment: If you are talking about the grey error page that says not found, you can add `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/" />` to the header in src/main/resources/templates/error.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `**` rule at the end of your `navbar.routes` to redirect to Home page. Below is the example:

```
{ path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
```

Comment: I have updated navbar.route.ts file as follow but still it is not working

`import { Route, Routes } from '@angular/router';
  import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
  import { HomeComponent } from '../../home';

export const navbarRoute: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: NavbarComponent,
    outlet: 'navbar'
},
{ path: '/**', component: HomeComponent}
];
`

it throws me me following error

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sdfsfsdf'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sdfsfsdf'**

Comment: try removing `/` before `**`

Comment: I have also tried after removing this but I am still getting same issue and i am using Jhipster and this Application is generated by Jhipster.